# Hacer un metodo post a las tablas diferentes de la misma bd

Tags: mysql, nodejs

Necesito enviar datos en un método post a las tablas de la misma bd.

```
userModel.insertUser =(userData,callback)=>{
    if (connection){
        connection.query(
            'INSERT INTO napi_user SET?',userData,
            (err,result)=> {
                if (err){
                    throw err;
                }else {
                    callback(null,{
                        'insertId':result.insertId
                    })
                }
            }
        )
    }
 }

User.insertUser(userData,(err,data)=>{
    if (data && data.insertId){
        res.json({
            success: true,
            msg:'dato insertado',
            data:data
        })
    } else {
        res.status(500).json({
            success:false,
            msg:'Error'
        })
    }
});
```

En postman necesito algo como esto :

```
{
  "user_name" : "nombre",   //TABLA NAPI_USER
  "user_pass" : "qwerty",   //TABLA NAPI_USER
  "usin_age"  : "18",       //TABLA NAPI_USER_INFO
  "usin_gen"  : "M",        //TABLA NAPI_USER_INFO      
  "Scores": [
           { "scor_score":10,"scor_torneo":"Torneo 1"}, //TABLA NAPI_SCORE
           { "scor_score":20,"scor_torneo":"Torneo 1"}, //TABLA NAPI_SCORE
          ]
}
```

La base de datos es así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo te recomiendo hacer un SP que controle la carga de las tres tablas.

Comment: podría funcionar igual un método de transacciones?

Comment: así es. En ese caso puede hacer un control más riguroso.